# Group Multiple Rows Into Single Row

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, group-by, multiple-columns

I have the table below:

```
|  ID  |  Description|  Shelf  |  QTY  |
----------------------------------------
|  10  | Apples      |    1    |   24  |
|  10  | Apples      |    2    |   28  |
|  10  | Apples      |    6    |   12  |
|  15  | Oranges     |    2    |   8   |
|  15  | Oranges     |    6    |   33  |
```

I need to do some updating to this table and put the Shelf and QTY in together as a group as shown below:

```
|  ID  |  Description|    Availability    |
-------------------------------------------
|  10  | Apples      |  1-24, 2-28, 6-12  |
|  15  | Oranges     |  2-8, 6-33         |
```

Basically, we are trying to group the shelf and QTY in one single line.
This is for reporting purposes only so I have to display the data in that way.

So far, I am able to display the two columns by concatenating them and adding the dash:

```
SELECT ID, Description, Shelf || '-' || QTY AS Availability FROM tbl_Products
```

To stitch them up together in a single line, I'm pretty sure I can use a WHILE loop to loop through the values and create the Availability string field before inserting it back to a temporary table then printing that out to the report.

But I'm not too sure about the performance. Since this query will be run in a big table, i'm just worried that it will slow down the database each time the report is being pulled.

So is there any other easier way I can achieve this?

Comment: Can there be NULL values? And your version of Postgres?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`string_agg` will fit the bill exactly:

```
SELECT   id, description, STRING_AGG(shelf || '-' || qty, ', ') AS Availability
FROM     tbl_Products
GROUP BY id, description
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `string_agg()`:

```
select id, description,
       string_agg( shelf || '-' || qty, ', ') as availability
from t
group by id, description;
```